# Can Java change url and part of page without whole page refresh?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, jsp

If you have dealt with react and react router, you see that on every page url and part of page changes, the page does not refresh whole page but only changes part of the page. And also in Google Chrome's console log it doesn't refreshes so that it proves it changes url without entire page refreshes.

I thought this kinds of technology could be only possible in some decent frontend framework like React or angular. But it wasn't, because,

I found a forum software called nodebb (it uses node.js which is probably spring boot equivalent) and it doesn't use react at all, but it shows it can actually do it with only backend framework like Node.js. You can check it at https://community.nodebb.org/

Since I realized it can be achieved without using decent frontend framework, now I wonder if it is possible in Java wothout using React or angular. I only experienced Spring boot backend so that I have no experience about Java's view templates/layers.

If it is possible in Java, what should I learn?

Comment: It's entirely possible with Spring web MVC.  You can use templates to generate server side content and inject it into a single page body.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not possible 'in Java', because you will always need front end code written in Javascript (or compiled to Javascript) to do the actual DOM manipulation and make the AJAX http requests to your backend. But yes, you can use any backend language or framework for this.

Comment: *"I wonder if it is possible in Java without using React or angular."* - Sure.  You can implement this with plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in JAVA, rather it requires an AJAX request to be fired from your frontend application. On a successful request the data is bound to a particular component. If you prefer to use Java for your web rendering try JSP or Thymeleaf as template engines